# Split a string to tow Datetime objects

Tags: php, regex

I have this kind of string `09:00-18:00`, I want to get 2 \DateTime. The time of the right part returns an object and that of the left part returns another object.
I tried to use split, but the my solution does not seems great that's why I'm asking for another solution.
This is my solution:

```
    // Get start time and end time separated by "-"
    $split = \preg_split('/[\s-]+/', $line['intervention_hour']);
    // Get hour number and minute separated by "h"
    $start = \preg_split('/[:]+/', $split[0]);
    $end = \preg_split('/[:]+/', $split[1]);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are your expecting result? Can you make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure your that your input will always have the same structure, you could use something like this:

```
list($start, $end) = explode('-', str_replace(':','h','09:00-18:00'));
```

Your variable $start will contain '09h00' and $end will contain '18h00'

Comment: Is it possible to check if my string flow this format "09:00-18:00" ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use  [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$line = '09:00-18:00';

$split = explode('-', $line);

$start = DateTime::createFromFormat ( 'H:m', $split[0]);
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat ( 'H:m', $split[1]);

print_r($start);
echo '>>>';
print_r($end);
```

You can check the online [Demo](https://3v4l.org/h2uuA)

Comment: Is it possible to check if my string flow this format "09:00-18:00" ?

Answer (score 1):

date_create and new DateTime recognize hh:mm and hh:mm:ss even without format specifications. The date is set to the current date.

```
$line = '09:00-18:00';

$parts = explode('-', $line);

$start = date_create($parts[0]);
$end   = date_create($parts[1]);

var_dump($start, $end);
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-11-07 09:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-11-07 18:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

A very short variant that returns an array with 2 datetime objects:

```
$line = '09:00-18:00';

$array = array_map('date_create',explode('-', $line));
```

Update:

A strict format check can be realized with regular expressions.

```
if(preg_match('/^([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]-([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/',$line)){
  //processing

}
else {
  //format error
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to check if my string flow this format "09:00-18:00" ?